# Query to fill ID column based on matching columns from different tables

Tags: mysql

SQL question.

I have 2 tables:

```
1. Clubs (2 columns - CID, Club)
2. Players (4 columns - Name,Position,CID,Club)
```

Situation:

```
In table 1 both columns are filled and have data.
In table 2 the columns Name, Position and club have data. The column CID is empty.
```

My aim is to fill the column CID (table 2) using the data from table 1 (CID) but only if the column Club (table 2) matches the value of the column Club (table 1).

I am pretty new to SQL, so not sure where to begin. I have been reading about UPDATE, JOIN but I'm a bit wary of how this should be accomplished.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple query:

```
UPDATE Players
JOIN Clubs ON Clubs.Club = Players.Club
SET Players.CID = Clubs.CID;
```

Comment: Hi Slava. Worked like a charm! Thanks!